# EMR fails to run python 3.x

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-emr

I added a step in EMR to run a pyspark job. However I end up getting the error

`TypeError: makedirs() got an unexpected keyword argument 'exist_ok'`

which makes me suspect that EMR default version python2.7 is being run. 
The ami version im using is 5.25.0 which is rather new and according to the documentation should come with 3.6 installed already.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3.6
```

I added the shebang to provide the executable. Is there something else to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is right. The system default version of python is 2.7 but there is also pythoh 3.x with `python3` command. You can change it by following the below document.

[How do I configure Amazon EMR to run a PySpark job using Python 3.4 or 3.6?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/emr-pyspark-python-3x/)

Basically, type the below command on the running cluster

```
sudo sed -i -e '$a\export PYSPARK_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python3' /etc/spark/conf/spark-env.sh
```

or set the configuration when you create the cluster such as

```
[
  {
     "Classification": "spark-env",
     "Configurations": [
       {
         "Classification": "export",
         "Properties": {
            "PYSPARK_PYTHON": "/usr/bin/python3"
          }
       }
    ]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

That is indeed the solution but it is worth mentioning that I am using a data pipeline to run the cluster. 
To provide this config, *if you choose to edit in architect* than provide a json config, you need to create a configuration object in resources section shown below. 
[image]

The configuration you create here will cascade an export configuration. See below. 
[image]

The property will be just "PYSPARK_PYTHON": "/usr/bin/python3" for key and value 
[image]

In your emr console, it should then show a configuration object as

```
spark-env.export
```

[image]